# Web3 version not same everywhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, metamask

I am initializing web3 from metamask ectension in react this way-

```
componentDidMount() {
     window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        let web3 = window.web3
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        console.log(web3.version)
     })
}
```

Above console.log give version `1.0.0-beta.22`, however when I call `web3.version` inside of other function inside the component-

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    let web3 = window.web3
    console.log(web3.version)
};
```

Here `console.log(web3.version)` gives `version 0.20.2`

Web3 version I have installed using npm is version `1.0.0-beta.22`. I guess 0.20.2 version is injected by metamask somehow. I want to use version `1.0.0-beta.22` everywhere. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was doing a silly mistake. Solution-

```
componentDidMount() {
     window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        let web3 = window.web3
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        console.log(web3.version)
     })
}
```